# can you please figure out error in my BFS code

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

[you can see image to check nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R127f.png)Question:by using BFS find path to sent Message from Sara to Uzma by using mutual friends
this code is giving error and not showing the path. can you please figure out the mistake ?
Note:neighbour is a friend of given node

```
import collections

class Node():
    #dictionary is use to make graph
    graph={} 
    def add_edge(self,node,neighbour):
        if node not in self.graph.keys():
            self.graph[node]=[neighbour]
        else:
            self.graph[node].append(neighbour)

    def show_graph(self):
        print(self.graph)

    def show_neigh(self,node):
        print(self.graph[node])

    def BFS(self,initial,final):
        visited,queue=set(), collections.deque([initial])
        visited.add(initial)
        while queue:
            vertex=queue.popleft()
            for adj in self.graph[vertex]:
                if adj == final:
                    visited.add(adj)
                    print("Message sent Successfully !",visited)
                    break
                if adj not in visited:
                    visited.add(adj)
                    queue.append(adj)

g=Node()
g.add_edge("Amina","Sara")
g.add_edge("Amina","Riaz")
g.add_edge("Riaz","Ali")
g.add_edge("Riaz","Ahmed")
g.add_edge("Ahmed","Ahsan")
g.add_edge("Ahmed","Amina")
g.add_edge("Rida","Taha")
g.add_edge("Rida","Hassan")
g.add_edge("Uzma","Taha")
g.add_edge("Uzma","Ahsan")

g.show_graph()
g.BFS("Sara","Uzma")
```

Comment: Please add the error you talk about. If the code runs it should be at least possible to debug it and figure out what is going on by looking at contents of the variables after each call to add_edge. E.g if after the first add_edge exists edge Amina->Sara and Sara->Amina. I think you will come to surprising revelation.

Comment: "*this code is giving error*" What is the error? Please [edit] to post the full Traceback and error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sara` is never added to the nodes of the graph: it is added to neighbours of `Anima` only. There is no path from `Sara` to `Uzma` because `Sara` is not in the graph's nodes. The `add_edge` does not create a node for the `neighbour`. `Sara` is never the `node`, it's always (once) the `neighbour`.

**tl;dr**: I suggest you to use dictionaries for both the graph's vertices and a vertex' adjacent nodes.

- A dictionary-based **undirected graph** requires that both the nodes are added to graph's nodes, and to the respective adjacency dictionaries:

  ```py
  # undirected graph
  class Graph():
      def __init__(self):
          self.nodes = {}

      def add_edge(self, u, v, weight=1):
          if not u in self.nodes:
              self.nodes[u] = {}
          if not v in self.nodes:
              self.nodes[v] = {}
          self.nodes[u][v] = weight
          self.nodes[v][u] = weight # missing in the directed graph

      ...
  ```
- A dictionary-based **directed graph** requires that  both the nodes are added to graph's nodes, and the head is added to the tail's adjacency dictionary only (the tail is not added to the adjacency dictionary of the head):

  ```py
  # directed graph
  class Graph():
      def __init__(self):
          self.nodes = {}

      def add_arrow(self, u, v, weight=1):
          if not u in self.nodes:
              self.nodes[u] = {}
          if not v in self.nodes:
              self.nodes[v] = {}
          self.nodes[u][v] = weight

      ...
  ```

Finally, reading the text of your homework(?), we see the word *mutual*, which explicits the kind of graph you need: an **undirected graph**.

Comment: yeah but question is find path from sara to uzma